# Spring i18n, проблема с кодировкой

Tags: java, spring, кодировка, i18n

Сконфигурировал Spring для интернализации и локализации, но столкнулся с проблемой в кодировке. Английские символы отображаются нормально, а вот вместо русского текста вопросительные знаки `???????`. Код конфигурации:

```
@Bean
public LocaleResolver localeResolver(){
    CookieLocaleResolver resolver = new CookieLocaleResolver();
    resolver.setDefaultLocale(new Locale("ru"));
    resolver.setCookieName("locale");
    resolver.setCookieMaxAge(60 * 60 * 24 * 365 * 10);
    return resolver;
}

@Bean
public MessageSource messageSource() {
    ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
    messageSource.setBasename("classpath:/i18n/messages");
    messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
    messageSource.setFallbackToSystemLocale(true);
    return messageSource;
}



@Override
public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
    LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor = new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
    localeChangeInterceptor.setParamName("lang");
    registry.addInterceptor(localeChangeInterceptor);
}
```

Также использую Thymeleaf:

```
<h1 th:text="#{message}"></h1>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Файлы `*.properties` должны быть сохранены в той же кодировке, которая указывается в `MessageSource`.